# Endpoint to get the system user stopped working in Facebook GraphAPI v11.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are having a problem to setup a system user in our customer’s business account (say Account B) from our business account (say account A), via the on-behalf-of (OBO) mechanism.

We are able to create the OBO relationship between the two accounts. Then we call the end point
***POST <customer_business_id>/access_token*** to create the system user. The call succeeds and sends us back an access token for the created system user. We verified the access token via Facebook’s access token debugger. The debugger showed that the token is valid, it belonged to the intended system user and it had the necessary permissions.

Now, when we call the endpoint ***GET /me*** using the above generated system user access token, we get the following error

*cannot resolve system user ID: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api*

We have the following permissions on the access token
*pages_show_list, ads_management, business_management, leads_retrieval, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_manage_ads, public_profile*

The Facebook app we are using is in the “In development” state and the Graph API version we are using is V11.0. We checked with the latest Graph API version of v14.0 and it did not work.

As of Feb-2022, the above end point was working fine with the “In development” app and Graph API version v11.0. Now it stopped working as explained above.

But, when we tried using another app that is of the type “Business”, the above GET /me endpoint worked.

Any help from you to resolve the above issue, will be much appreciated.

Thanks.